# How do I play video in my Flutter Desktop Application

Tags: flutter, dart-pub, video-player, flutter-windows

I want to play video files (stored in my local machine) in a **desktop** application developed by flutter. But unfortunately I couldn't do it. Most popular video player packages do not support **windows** platform. I tried with [dart_vlc](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_vlc/versions/0.0.2/example)  but it's not working as documented. I followed the exact example given there.

Now I really need to play video files in my application but can't find a way to do it. Does anyone has any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This [dart_vlc](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_vlc/example) works perfectly on windows platform. All I needed to do is go through the instructions mentioned in *Readme* section and change in my **windows/runner/main.cpp** file as mentioned [here](https://github.com/alexmercerind/flutter_native_view#setup).

Note: Previously I mistakenly followed the older version of *dart_vlc* package.